# How to fix json error:JSON_ERROR_NONE?

Tags: php, json

I have the variable $data that prints correctly the data that I post,but right after json_decode it returns null,here is the data before json_decode:

```
  {
    "html":"",
    "mobile":"",
    "isSmsLong":0,
    "hasShortUrl":1,
    "text":"http:\/\/google.com\/",
    "typeCampaign":"2",
    "id_content":"24",
    "id":"26"
  }
```

I writed the code below to figure out the error:

```
$data = \json_decode(($data));

if (json_last_error() == 0) { print_r(1111);exit;}
if (json_last_error() == 1) { print_r(22222);exit;}
if (json_last_error() == 2) { print_r(3333);exit;}
if (json_last_error() == 3) { print_r(444);exit;}
if (json_last_error() == 4) { print_r(5555);exit;}
if (json_last_error() == 5) { print_r(6666);exit;}
```

it prints 1111, so the error is

> JSON_ERROR_NONE:No error has occurred

can't find how to fix this error ,Any help please?

Comment: Please also add the content of `$data`. We can't guess what is there and why it's not working.

Comment: @DanielDudas question edited .

Comment: `JSON_ERROR_NONE` is not an error.

Comment: I tried your code and is working ok. No `null` returned. Check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ced007c3f8d216da338951017675b7c1caac658

Comment: so the code is right inline but in my project it returns null, what could be the issue ?

Comment: You have misunderstood the `json_last_error()` function. It returned 0 which is also equivalent to false. That means no errors found at all, which means your json_decode() executed without error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: if (json_last_error()) { echo json_last_error_msg();exit;} //is sufficient